# Iframe - performing SSO and accessing page behind authentication wall with iframe

Tags: iframe, single-sign-on, gooddata, cross-origin-embedder-policy, cross-origin-resource-policy

I have 2 domains, one that hosts my app - `myapp`, and the other that hosts gooddata dashboards - `analytics.myapp`. I would like to embed a [gooddata](https://www.gooddata.com/developers/cloud-native/doc/) dashboard to a page in my app. I have set the frame-src to allow requests from the domain where the dashboard is:

```
set $CSP "${CSP}; frame-src https://analytics.myapp.com/";

add_header Content-Security-Policy ${CSP};
```

I have also set the `CORS` at the host `analytics.myapp` to allow requests from `myapp` domain:

```
ingress:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin: "http://localhost:10000, https://myapp.com"
```

I want to embed an iframe with content from the domain `analytics.myapp`, which is possible to see only after you are authenticated, into a page on `myapp` domain. Right now when I load the content the iframe is displaying a login page, and if I try to log in through an iframe, I get an error:

```
Blocked autofocusing on a <input> element in a cross-origin subframe.
```

If I login to the `analytics.myapp` with a user in a different tab that doesn't work, since cookies are not sent to the `myapp` domain.
I see that it is possible to authenticate through an api in their [docs](https://www.gooddata.com/developers/cloud-native/doc/1.3/administration/auth/user-token/). And they also have [docs](https://www.gooddata.com/developers/cloud-native/doc/1.3/getting-started/create-ui-sdk-app/#embed-a-dashboard) on how  to embed their dashboard, but in order to see the embedded dashboard docs say:

*Users must be workspace members to see the embedded dashboard.*

I don't have SSO (single sign on) implemented yet, but I wonder once I implement it, will there be still issues with CORS? I would imagine that once I implement this, and a user from `myapp` domain goes to a page where I have an iframe with the embedded dashboard from `analytics.myapp`, that they will be redirected to an auth endpoint on `myapp` where user will be authenticated through SSO for `analytics.myapp` and redirected back to `analytics.myapp` with the user data.

Now is that the correct flow and will that work with an iframe, are there any CORS issues with this, and can that be implemented like that?

Comment: How about if you authenticate on a separate tab, and then open your page with the iframe, are you logged in then?

Comment: @php_nub_qq no, I am not authenticated then either

Comment: You probably won't want to use the API unless you're building your own app, sounds like you will want to use [OAuth/OIDC](https://www.gooddata.com/developers/cloud-native/doc/1.3/administration/auth/external-oidc/#create-an-oauth2-client)

Comment: what is the question here? is it how to resolve the CROS issue? or it’s about ‘gooddata’ service and if they allow you to use their service this way?

Comment: it is about CORS issue @GoDLighT